# using usestate variable in while loop

Tags: reactjs

```
await watchProfit(response);
    
const watchProfit = async (response) => {
    while (calculateProfitPercentage(response.data.avgPrice , strike) < 
incrementalBuyPercentage) {
        console.log('Checking profit...', strike);
    }
    console.log('Profit threshold reached. Proceeding to the next iteration.');
};

const calculateProfitPercentage = (averageBuyPrice,currPrice) => {
    if (averageBuyPrice === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    console.log(averageBuyPrice,strike,'achha')
    const profit = currPrice - averageBuyPrice;
    const profitPercentage = (profit / averageBuyPrice) * 100;
    return profitPercentage;
};
```

In this scenario, 'strike' is a state variable.

My goal is to pass the current strike price to the 'watchProfit' function for continuous tracking of the profit percentage. The process should exit the while loop once the profit threshold is reached.

However, within the while loop, the 'strike' variable does not reflect its updated value; instead, it retains an older value.

How can I ensure that the updated 'strike' value is passed each time it changes, allowing for continuous and accurate tracking of the profit percentage?

Comment: state variables updates asynchronously, so this is expected. Provide complete context regarding how you upate state variable

Answer (score -1):

To solve the issue of the strike state variable not updating inside the while loop in your React component, you need to understand that state updates in React are asynchronous and are not immediately reflected. When you use a state variable inside a while loop, it captures the state at the time the function was invoked, leading to the issue you're experiencing.

To address this, you can use a combination of React's useEffect and useState hooks to continuously check for changes in the strike state and act accordingly. Here's an approach you can take:

1. Set up a useEffect hook that watches for changes in the strike state.
2. Within the useEffect, call the watchProfit function.
3. Modify watchProfit to use a recursive setTimeout approach instead of a while loop, ensuring it gets the updated strike value each time it's called.

#### Here's an example of how you can implement this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    const YourComponent = () => {
        const [strike, setStrike] = useState(initialStrikeValue); // initialize your state
    
        useEffect(() => {
            watchProfit();
            // Other dependencies can be added if necessary
        }, [strike]); // This useEffect will run every time `strike` changes
    
        const watchProfit = async () => {
            if (calculateProfitPercentage(response.data.avgPrice, strike) < incrementalBuyPercentage) {
                console.log('Checking profit...', strike);
                setTimeout(watchProfit, 1000); // Check again after a delay (e.g., 1000 ms)
            } else {
                console.log('Profit threshold reached. Proceeding to the next iteration.');
            }
        };
    
        const calculateProfitPercentage = (averageBuyPrice, currPrice) => {
            if (averageBuyPrice === 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            const profit = currPrice - averageBuyPrice;
            const profitPercentage = (profit / averageBuyPrice) * 100;
            return profitPercentage;
        };
    
        // ... rest of your component
    };
```

This approach ensures that every time the strike state changes, the useEffect hook triggers the watchProfit function, which will now use the updated strike value. The setTimeout function is used to repeatedly call watchProfit after a set delay, effectively replacing the while loop and avoiding blocking the main thread.

Remember to clear the timeout when the component unmounts or before starting a new timeout to avoid memory leaks:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutId = setTimeout(watchProfit, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}, [strike]);
```

This is a more React-friendly way to handle continuous checks or polling mechanisms that rely on updated state values.

#### Full code example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
    const [strike, setStrike] = useState(initialStrikeValue); // Initialize your state

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = watchProfit();
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }, [strike]); // This useEffect will run every time `strike` changes

    const watchProfit = async () => {
        if (calculateProfitPercentage(response.data.avgPrice, strike) < incrementalBuyPercentage) {
            console.log('Checking profit...', strike);
            return setTimeout(watchProfit, 1000); // Check again after a delay (e.g., 1000 ms)
        } else {
            console.log('Profit threshold reached. Proceeding to the next iteration.');
        }
    };

    const calculateProfitPercentage = (averageBuyPrice, currPrice) => {
        if (averageBuyPrice === 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        const profit = currPrice - averageBuyPrice;
        const profitPercentage = (profit / averageBuyPrice) * 100;
        return profitPercentage;
    };

    // ... rest of your component
};

export default YourComponent;
```